# "Referer" header is missing when user clicks on a link from inside an iframe that overrides a newtab in Chrome

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, http-headers, http-referer

## Question

Is it an expected behavior of a browser acting like that?

#### Related Chromium bug

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=492761

## Steps

1. create an [empty extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted) for Chrome
2. put a newtab override into `manifest.json`: `"chrome_url_overrides": {"newtab": "newtab.html"}`
3. create `newtab.html` (`chrome-extension://<extension_id>/newtab.html`), create an iframe and load some page into it, e.g. `https://<some_page>.com/`
4. put a link to that page, e.g. `https://example.org/`
5. click that link and observe the request

## Expected result

The "Referer" header should be present, e.g.:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://<some_page>.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4
Cookie: ...
```

## Actual result

There's no "Referer" header:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.65 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,ru;q=0.4
Cookie: ...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"eroman at chromium.org" nails it down (see linked chromium bug report, already closed).

The thing is, when iframe contains a secured (https) page, but iframe itself is contained in a non-secured page (replaced Chrome newtab, in this case), then a non-secured (http) request is made when user click on a link from within that iframe.

[RFC 2616 section 15.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-15.1.3) steps in saying:

```
Clients SHOULD NOT include a Referer header field in a (non-secure)
HTTP request if the referring page was transferred with a secure
protocol.
```

This makes described case a desired one, so browser behaves as expected by the standard.

Moreover, if a link points to a non-secure page, e.g. http://example.org/, it would be a normal (non-secure) http request, so "Referer" would be omitted - just because a referring page is secure. This is, of course, still valid even if there's no iframe wrapping a secured page.